# Is Acronis True Image encryption safe?

Tags: encryption, software, backup

This question [has been asked before](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/153553/is-acronis-true-image-encryption-secure) but a lot of time has passed since then.

The older question had an answer that the Eula said that Acronis can decrypt the data. I can no longer find that part.

Can you trust their encryption? By trust I mean that nobody can decrypt it (not even Acronis) as long as you have a very strong key and your encryption is set to AES-256?

Comment: Please actually link to the older question instead of talking about it obliquely

Comment: Please do not repost old questions. The standard here is to update answers on the old questions instead of re-asking the same question in the future.

Comment: Hi @schroeder, sadly the old question doesn't have the same activity as it used to have before so is there a way to bring attention to that question. I know about bounties but i don't have reputation for them.

Comment: https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/is-a-question-asking-if-old-answers-to-same-similar-question-are-still-valid-acc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reverse engineering the software and analyzing what all data is being sent, there is a minimum amount of trust that must be given to the application.

If you want to go by what they have publicly stated, the current [EULA](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/support/eula.html) (as of 3/11/2021) states that "Acronis cannot decrypt your files if You have elected to encrypt."
This would imply that Acronis does not have a method of decrypting the (encrypted) data you send to them.

Additionally, in 2017 the [GM](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/blog/authors/gaidar-magdanurov) stated that [Acronis does not have the ability to decrypt data that users uploaded if they have encrypted it locally](https://forum.acronis.com/forum/acronis-true-image-2017-forum/acronis-aes-encryption-backdoored). Data uploaded in plaintext and encrypted by Acronis can (by necessity) be decrypted by them.